Create an Attack-Release Envelope for a 555 Synth
So I am designing a synthesizer based on the 555 chip, and I'm having trouble incorporating an AR (attack-release) envelope without changing the oscillator frequency. In more detail:
I have the circuit below, which is basically straight from Forest Mim's book (Version 2), but I have also experimented with connecting the speaker high (Version 1). The way I understand this circuit is the cycle charges through R1C, discharges through R2C, and that's how you set the frequency. I've calculated specific values of RC to produce specific frequencies. I want to add an AR envelope without changing the frequency it produces (so I can tune it first, and then change the envelope settings). (I did these calculations for V2, but I can do it again for V1 if that's important.)
Q1: If the frequency comes from the cycling of R1C and R2C, why does changing the capacitor between the speaker and ground (say, 4.7 uF to 1.5 uF) change the frequency? (I've checked, it changes it dramatically)

I have seen several designs for AR circuits, and I built the one from the Noise Toaster* (here). I first connected the output to the high side of the whole circuit (at +9 V), but that changed the frequency pretty substantially. Slightly better results where when I connected the output of the AR to 8,4, and speaker (V1), and left R1 at 9V. In that case, I found that if I kept the pot values to 10-20k on the attack, that changed the frequency only by 5-10 Hz. That's passable, I suppose, but not great for this thing staying in tune with the band.
Q2: I understand these AR circuits as RC-charge/discharge cycles with longer time constants than the oscillator - is there a straightforward way to connect such an AR generator to the 555 such that the natural R1C/R2C cycle is not impacted by the envelope?
I have found a few other options for such AR circuits + 555, but none of them directly address this issue. For example:
https://electro-music.com/forum/topic-61297.html
https://electro-music.com/forum/topic-60172.html

the ADSR envelope should be separately generated from the tone

@jsotola: absolutely - but how do I accomplish that? It seems that if I add anything like a resistor or capacitor to the circuit, the frequency will change.
